# fade out some area and fade in other one

Tags: jquery

I have a login form and a link with 'Register' title beneath the form. I want it when user click on 'Register' link, the login fade out and register form fade in. I used the following script to that :

```
  $("#loginArea").fadeOut(2000, function () {
                        $("#RegisterArea").fadeIn(2000, function () { 
                        $("#RegisterArea").empty().append(mydata); });
                        //$("#RegisterArea").empty().
                    });
```

using the above code, the login form fade out, but fade in for regsiter form does not work and just put 'mydata' content in 'RegisterArea' without animating.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to do this:

```
$("#loginArea").fadeOut(2000, function () {
    $("#RegisterArea").empty().hide().append(mydata);
    $("#RegisterArea").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

If the Register area is empty while fading in you won't see it, so first fill it with content, then fade it in :)

Comment: `$("#RegisterArea").empty().hide().append(mydata).fadeIn(2000);` would do :)

Comment: +1; Also, if it isn't initially set to be hidden (which you also added), it won't fade in.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working fine for me.  See this demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/UDdZ9/

Is it possible that you aren't making your `#RegisterArea` initially hidden?  Or that IDs you're using to select your objects are incorrect (that they don't match the underlying HTML)?  I ran into those issues while getting the demo to work correctly.

To hide your `#RegisterArea` initially, you can use [the jQuery `.hide` method](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), or you can set its style in CSS to `display:none`.

If this doesn't help, you might want to try running this in chrome, open the script console, and see if you're getting and scripting errors on your page.  To open the script console, <kbd>F12</kbd>, then click the `Show Console` button on the lower-left corner of the window.

Here's the working code from that demo I made with your code.

HTML:

```
<div id="loginArea">
    <a id="register">Click me to register</a>
</div>
<div id="RegisterArea">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#loginArea {
    background:grey;
}

#RegisterArea {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:green;
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#register").click(function() {
    $("#loginArea").fadeOut(2000, function() {
        $("#RegisterArea").fadeIn(2000, function() {
            var mydata = "test123";
            $("#RegisterArea").empty().append(mydata);
        });
    });
});
```